# Create binary tree from existing location table with parent_id relationship

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've spent half a day looking into Binary Trees and Binary Search Trees and simply cannot get my head around them, or how it applies to what I have here. All the reading I have looked at is rather confusing in concept, and none give real world examples.

I have inherited a MySQL and PHP system that has a table of geographical locations. This is hierarchical by nature and all records are linked to their immediate parent via a parent_id field.

e.g. New Zealand -> North Island -> Auckland -> Auckland City

This table also has two fields called "lft" and "rgt" which are already populated. My job is to alter this table with more (and changed) geographical locations, and thus, update these lft and rgt values.

I understand that if I look at a child node's lft and rgt values and write a query to the effect of: SELECT * FROM table WHERE lft <= child_left AND rgt > child_rgt, I will get a chain of ancestors.

But I don't understand the logic of this. I don't follow the theory behind assigning these lft and rgt values to a record. They certainly don't appear to have any correlation to the unique id of the records themselves.

Can someone point me to a decent resource with examples? Or have a simple way of explaining BST's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future searches:

I found this old article from 2003 that explains it on a basic level very well.

Page 3 also has a PHP function for walking the tree and assigning left and right values to each item using an existing parent as a reference.

http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/